# How to use gulp-sprite-generator

Tags: sass, gulp, sprite

I would like create a sprite with Gulp, create a CSS file with coordinates automatically and insert the image from this sprite with name, like :

```
.my_class {
    background-image: url("images/my-image.png");
}
```

After a research I would like use [gulp-sprite-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sprite-generator) but I do not understand how I can use it.

In my gulp file I add the configuration of this plugin :

```
gulp.task('sprites', function () {
    var spriteOutput = gulp.src(app + '/css/*.css')
        .pipe(plugins.spriteGenerator({
            baseUrl: 'app/images/sprite',
            spriteSheetName: 'sprite.png',
            spriteSheetPath: 'dist/images/'
        })
    );

    spriteOutput.css.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'));
    spriteOutput.img.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images/'));
});
```

But when I call `gulp sprites` in a Terminal, no sprites are created.

So, I guess I need use the CSS for tell him to create some sprite from the sprite folder but I don't get it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do have same problem....!! I get following message 

`[gulp-sprite-generator] Created 0 sprite(s) from 0 images, saved 0% requests`

Comment: Did you have some news ? I'm stick here...

Answer (score 1):

I have done some work around and found **`gulp.spritesmith`** plugin

> https://github.com/twolfson/gulp.spritesmith

using  this plugins I am able to create sprites image and css for my application.

that's how I did it...

```
var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');

// Sprites task - create sprite image
gulp.task('sprites', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src(paths.source.images).pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.png',
    cssName: 'sprite.css',
    imgPath: paths.build.images + 'sprite.png'
  }));
    spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.css));
    spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build.images));
});
```

this way you'll get **sprite.css** file in destination css folder and **sprite.png** in destination images folder.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example – https://github.com/alex-chuev/gulp-sprite-example. It is usable.

But I also met a problem. I had saved my images from Photoshop with `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` and I got the same message:

> Created 0 sprite(s) from 0 images, saved 0% requests

I have resolved the issue by disabling the "Interlaced" checkbox in the save dialog:

[image: The Protoshop image save dialog]